realtime_tools::RealTimePublisher crushes gazebo simulation
i have difficulties in simulation my controller, particulary in using realtime_tools::RealTimePublisher using ros-noetic.
This is how I use object realtime_pub_:
if(realtime_pub_->trylock()){

        if(!id_solver_->CartToJnt(*q, *q_dot, *q_dot_dot, Wrenches, *torques_) != 0){
            ROS_ERROR("Could not compute joint torques! Setting all torques to zero!");
            realtime_pub_->unlock();
        }
        ROS_INFO("Computed torques!");

        realtime_pub_->msg_.header.stamp = time;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ){
            realtime_pub_->msg_.torque_error[i] = (*js_torques_)(i) - (*torques_)(i);
            realtime_pub_->msg_.joint_name[i] = joint_names_[i];
        }

        realtime_pub_->unlockAndPublish();
    }

After this gazebo sends me these messages in the order:
[ INFO] [1732756719.215477078, 6.225000000]: Computed torques!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 25417, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/roman/.ros/log/acc998f4-ad26-11ef-97ca-cfcc94db4fc7/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/roman/.ros/log/acc998f4-ad26-11ef-97ca-cfcc94db4fc7/gazebo-2*.log

I think the problem with method UnlockAndPublish() but i'm not sure. Also, I dont manage to read the log file gazebo-2.log because in the directory there is no such file.
Will appreciate any help!

You code may unlock the object twice. That is very likely to cause problems.

But I have "red flag" ROS_ERROR: if something went wrong i would have recieved the message before the double realtime.unlock().

Could you please see that question https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/113961/controller-doesnt-subscribe-on-topic-joint-states
