Controller doesn't subscribe on topic /joint_states
As i mentioned in my previous question, my controller acts wierdly. The problem is with subscribing to the topic "/joint_states" as i discovered.
Particulary, i have the part of the code below:
    void KukaStateController::update(const ros::Time &time, const ros::Duration &period){

        ros::Subscriber ext_wrenches_sub = nh_.subscribe<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped>
                                            ("ext_wrenches", 10, &KukaStateController::ext_wrench_cb, this);
        
        ros::Subscriber js_callback_sub = nh_.subscribe("/joint_states", 10, &KukaStateController::jsCallback, this);

        if(realtime_pub_->trylock()){

            if(!id_solver_->CartToJnt(*q, *q_dot, *q_dot_dot, Wrenches, *torques_) != 0){
                ROS_ERROR("Could not compute joint torques! Setting all torques to zero!");
            }
            realtime_pub_->msg_.header.stamp = time;

            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ){
                realtime_pub_->msg_.angles[i] = (*q)(i);
                realtime_pub_->msg_.torque_error[i] = (*js_torques_)(i) - (*torques_)(i);
                
            }

            realtime_pub_->unlockAndPublish();
        }
    }

    void KukaStateController::stopping(const ros::Time& time){}

    void KukaStateController::ext_wrench_cb(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped::ConstPtr &msg){
        KDL::Wrench w(KDL::Vector(msg->wrench.force.x, msg->wrench.force.y, msg->wrench.force.z), 
                  KDL::Vector(msg->wrench.torque.x, msg->wrench.torque.y, msg->wrench.torque.z));
        Wrenches.push_back(w);
        ROS_INFO("updated Wrenches");
    }

    void KukaStateController::jsCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr &msg){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < msg->name.size(); i++){
            joint_names_.push_back(msg->name[i]);
            (*q)(i) = msg->position[i];
            (*q_dot)(i) = msg->velocity[i]; 
            (*js_torques_)(i) = msg->effort[i];
            (*q_dot_dot)(i) = 0;
        }
        ROS_INFO("updated joint_states");
    }

Simply, i publish the torque error and angles into the topic 'kuka_state', but i recieved the following message with empty angles:
header: 
  seq: 520
  stamp: 
    secs: 5
    nsecs: 953000000
  frame_id: ''
angles: []
torque_error: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---

I think the problem is with subcribing to the external topics, but as always i am not sure. I have also tried to subscribe like this:
ros::Subscriber js_callback_sub =nh_.subscribe<sensor_msg::JointState>                                         ("angles",10,&KukaStateController::jsCallback, this);
But nothing have changed. Would appriciate any help.

I haven't seen your other question, are you using ros control?
If yes, it's not typical to subscribe inside the update function. And usually controllers don't subscribe to joint states.
I could try to help, but could you post a bit more information about what you'd like this controller to do (pseudo code is fine), and whether you're using ros(2) control. Or a link to a git repo would be cool too.

I simply want to read the joint's angles in realtime and then calculate smth.
Here is my github link Controllers. Open only kuka_controllers pack
